# Javascript Not Sending The Form Details To The PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to submit user details from a login form to a PHP file using Javascript. I have this code but is not working. I have reviewed the javascript code to see whether there are any errors but I can't find any. The form looks like this:

```
<div class="container_log">
  <div class="login_form justify-content-center">
    <div class="user_card">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="brand_logo_container">
          <img src="images/fevicon/logo.png" class="brand_logo" alt="logo">
        </div>
      </div>  
      <form>
        <div class="d-block justify-content-center form_container">
          <div id="message" style="color: #ffffff;"></div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>         
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="txt_uname" id="txt_uname" class="form-control input_user" required="" />
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>          
            </div>
            <input type="password" name="txt_pwd" id="txt_pwd" class="form-control input_pass" required="" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline" />
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlInline">Remember me</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
          <button type="button" name="but_submit" id="but_submit" class="btn login_btn">Login</button> 
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="mt-4">
        <div class="justify-content-center">
          <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The script looks like this. I checked for any mistakes but I can see the code is fine. would someone help me see what is wrong with this code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#but_submit").click(function(){
            var username = $("#txt_uname").val().trim();
            var password = $("#txt_pwd").val().trim();
            if( username != "" && password != "" ){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'login.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:{username:username,password:password},
                    success:function(response){
                        var msg = "";
                        if(response == 1){
                            window.location = "index.php";
                        }
                        else if(response == 2) {
                                msg = "Invalid username or password!";
                        }
                        else {
                            if (response == 0) {
                                msg = "Invalid username and password!";
                            }
                            else {
                                msg = "Something went wrong. Please contact support.";
                                alert(response);
                                window.location = "watchpost_error";
                            }
                        }
                        $("#message").html(msg);
                    },
                     error: function(request, response, status, xhr, status, error) {
                     }
                });
            }
            else {
                var msg = "Please input all the fields!";
            }
            $("#message").html(msg);
        });

    });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you actually have to use the "network-inspector" in your browsers dev-tools, to check whether the request was made and what parameters are submitted or maybe you see the console error that prevents that

Comment: ***It is not necessary to [trim or escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You're submitting the form, listen `submit` event of the form instead of clicks on the submit button, and prevent the default action of the submit event.

Comment: just by looking at your code you are submitting the form regular, non ajax just check for this

Comment: Your button is inside form, and I don't see you are preventing form from being submitted the regular way, I have a feeling when you press button page refresh itself?

Answer (score 0):

Your script works. I adjusted it slightly so it can be demonstrated in a snippet:

```js
// test AJAX servlet: returns true if username=='harry' && password=='potter'
const echoURL=da=>URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob([JSON.stringify(da.username=='harry'&&da.password=='potter'?1:2)],{type: "text/json"}) );
// ===================================================================================================

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#but_submit").click(function(){
            var username = $("#txt_uname").val().trim();
            var password = $("#txt_pwd").val().trim();
            if( username != "" && password != "" ){
                $.ajax({
                    url: echoURL({username,password}),
                    type:'GET', // testing with URL.createObjectURL() only possible with GET
                    // data:{username:username,password:password},
                    success:function(response){
                        var msg = ""; 
                        if(response == 1){
                                msg = "login OK!";
                                setTimeout(()=>location.href='https://sallymassmann.de',1000);
                        }
                        else if(response == 2) {
                                msg = "Invalid username or password!";
                        }
                        else {
                            if (response == 0) {
                                msg = "Invalid username and password!";
                            }
                            else {
                                msg = "Something went wrong. Please contact support.";
                                alert(response);
                                window.location = "watchpost_error";
                            }
                        }
                        $("#message").html(msg);
                    },
                     error: function(request, response, status, xhr, status, error) {
                     }
                });
            }
            else {
                var msg = "Please input all the fields!";
            }
            $("#message").html(msg);
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container_log">
  <div class="login_form justify-content-center">
    <div class="user_card">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="brand_logo_container">
          <img src="images/fevicon/logo.png" class="brand_logo" alt="logo">
        </div>
      </div>  
      <form>
        <div class="d-block justify-content-center form_container">
          <div id="message"></div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>         
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="txt_uname" id="txt_uname" class="form-control input_user" required="" />
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>          
            </div>
            <input type="password" name="txt_pwd" id="txt_pwd" class="form-control input_pass" required="" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline" />
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlInline">Remember me</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
          <button type="button" name="but_submit" id="but_submit" class="btn login_btn">Login</button> 
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="mt-4">
        <div class="justify-content-center">
          <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```